# String:String? array instead of String:String array breaks ForEach in SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my array:

```
class Storages: ObservableObject {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let uid = UserAuth().uid ?? "<uid>"
    
    @Published var photos: [String:String?] = [
        "img1": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "img1"),
        "img2": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "img2"),
        "img3": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "img3"),
    ]
```

And here is my view:

```
struct EditProfile: View {
    @ObservedObject var storage = Storages()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Points")
            .font(Font.system(size: 21))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            HStack {
                ForEach(storage.photos.sorted(by: <), id: \.key){ (key,val) in
                    EditableCircleImage(key: key, imgName: val)
                }
            }
```

If I change by `photos` dictionary from `[String:String?]` to `[String:String]` (by putting in `?? ""` to prevent `nil` value - then it will work. But I want to keep `nil` values as I need to know when an array item value is nil.

Here is the `struct` I pass into my for each:

```
struct EditableCircleImage: View {
    @ObservedObject var storage = Storages()
    let key: String
    let imgName: String?
```

Any idea why I can't use a `[String:String?]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Compiler error? Run-time error? ...

Comment: There isn't really an informative error. It says: `Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code` and `error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'App' from project 'App')` when I run the app - there is no compile time error, Xcode says `an internal error occured. Source editor is limited. Attempting to restore functionality...`

Comment: Xcode 12 gives error for `sorted(by: <)`. Did you overload it? If not, that is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variant. Tested with some replicated code on Xcode 12b.

```
ForEach(storage.photos.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }), id: \.key){ (key,val) in
    EditableCircleImage(key: key, imgName: val)
}
```

Comment: Yes this fixes the problem - thankyou. PS: What do you mean by "overloading" in this context?